# Overlapping table with line ssrs 208

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I have to make a report with a fixed table size. It's pretty easy, just have to put a table and a line above it, but ssrs is moving the line and I think it's a problem of overlapping.

I set the textboxes inside the tablix to not grow.

Thats how I designed the report:

[image: Overlapping]

And that's what's rendering:
[image: Overlapping2]

Any ideas of how I can achieve that?

Comment: Are you using a line object? If so, use the border setting on the column instead, this should render the way you want; select the cell in design, properties, and set borderstyle, borderwidth, bordercolor

Comment: I tried but it continue overlapping @SqlACID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I put all the controls into a rectangle and rendered fine.